# XCode 4 hangs at "Loading Project"

Tags: xcode4

I don't have much to go on... XCode 4 is hanging at startup with "Loading Project". My build fails but I can't access the errors. This is happening with a project that worked in a previous version of XCode. It also happens for new projects.

Comment: I've managed to find the build errors (using the 'issues' window), but I still can't figure out why the project won't fully load.

Comment: Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9936904/836407.  It worked for me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had a simliar issue. I deleted `project.xcworkspace` and `xcuserdata` inside the `.xcodeproj` directory and I was able to open the project file.

Comment: This also fixes the issue for me, but I have to perform that same delete operation on those two files each time I restart the computer.  Anyway we can stop this from reoccurring?

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue at the moment, it was after pressing Continue a bunch of times on some internal logic errors. I think the .xcodeproj file is corrupted. Are you sure it won't even work on new projects?

My solution would be to delete it and create a new one, re-add all of the dependencies, build settings and existing source/resources, and then restart Xcode and try opening the project again. It should work this time. It has for me anyway.

Another issue could be if you're creating a new project on network storage and then it's somehow not loading all of the associated files because of a network error. Try moving the files to local storage if this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue which ended up being caused by a folder named "~" in my application resources directory. Deleting this directory resolved the hang.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue, Xcode 4, after trying to add a framework and Xcode added everything under Xcode.app. It did not hang with the processing gear forever probably because my computer uses an SSD drive. After many minutes of the spinning gear, it was loaded and I removed the 'Reference' (right mouse click).