# Xcode 4 and 5 frozen with an empty tab on Launch

Tags: xcode

I've got this weird problem from last night, where I cannot open Xcode anymore!

It is stuck with an empty tab loading view, and is just not responding... :-/

I have deleted Xcode4 and re-installed, it keep giving me that same problem... And also tried with Xcode 5, and still.... so I guess the problem is somewhere on my computer... What can I do?

Really need to fix this for work.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found my solution on a similar linked problem :

[Xcode freezes on startup while loading project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11247008/xcode-freezes-on-startup-while-loading-project)

Due to the restore feature, all the windows you left open in a given application remain open when you relaunch it. To avoid this, discard the previously open windows by holding the option key while pressing CMD+Q. Try starting Xcode and quitting it with option held before it's had a chance to open your windows, then re-launch it and it shouldn't try to open the windows.

Fixed the problem for me.