# Xcode 6.4 not responding after launching simulator

Tags: ios, xcode6

I'm running iOS app in simulator. It was working fine, suddenly since this morning Xcode stops responding (shows busy indicator on mouse over to Xcode window) immediately after launching the app in Simulator. Had to force kill Xcode and restarted OS as well, but still it is same. I gave it ~30 mins, but Xcode is still busy. Simulator is working fine though.

Any suggestion ?

Rose

Comment: possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11247008/xcode-freezes-on-startup-while-loading-project

Comment: saved me a lot of time, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There were many different suggestions posted at [Xcode freezes on startup while loading project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11247008/xcode-freezes-on-startup-while-loading-project) One that worked for me was the removal of xcuserdata dir:

> cd ~/project_dir; find . -name "xcuserdata" -exec rm -rf {} \;