# XCode 4.6.3 crash when opening one project

Tags: ios, xcode

I keep two versions of Xcode, 4.6.3 and 5.0.2, and worked for some days, there was nothing wrong. But today when I opened one of my projects with Xcode 4.6.3, it crashed several seconds later. Repeated many times, but other projects that are open with Xcode 5.0.2 not.

I have uninstalled both versions of Xcode, re-installed Xcode 4.6.3, but the problem still exists. That reason why I do not use Xcode 5.0.2 is because I use a library that Xcode 5.0.2 does not support.

Could someone help? Thanks very much!

Crash report below:

```
Process:         Xcode [696]
Path:            /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:      com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:         4.6.3 (2068)
Build Info:      IDEApplication-2068000000000000~3
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [258]
Responsible:     Xcode [696]
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2013-11-21 17:19:39.479 +0800
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.9 (13A603)
Report Version:  11
Anonymous UUID:  053ABB38-41BB-9CC2-9E8F-6691450D069B


Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000028

VM Regions Near 0x28:
--> 
    __TEXT                 00000001060ed000-00000001060f0000 [   12K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 4H1503
objc[696]: garbage collection is ON

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   com.apple.CoreText              0x00007fff8e73a0cb TLine::AppendRun(TCFRef<CTRun const*>&&) + 75
1   com.apple.CoreText              0x00007fff8e74d959 TLine::AppendPartialRun(CTRun const*, CFRange) + 53
2   com.apple.CoreText              0x00007fff8e74d8eb TLine::CopyStringRange(TLine const&, CFRange) + 257
3   com.apple.CoreText              0x00007fff8e783b27 TTypesetter::FindGraphicalBreakInconsistent(std::__1::tuple<TLine const*, TCharStream const*, void const* (*)(__CTRun const*, __CFString const*, void*), void*, std::__1::shared_ptr<TBidiLevelsProvider>*, unsigned int, unsigned char> const&, TLine const&, CFRange, double, double, unsigned char, long&, double&) + 245
4   com.apple.CoreText              0x00007fff8e782e08 TTypesetter::FindGraphicalBreak(std::__1::tuple<TLine const*, TCharStream const*, void const* (*)(__CTRun const*, __CFString const*, void*), void*, std::__1::shared_ptr<TBidiLevelsProvider>*, unsigned int, unsigned char> const&, long, double, double, std::__1::function<unsigned char (long)>) + 490
5   com.apple.CoreText              0x00007fff8e782b14 TTypesetter::SuggestClusterBreak(std::__1::tuple<TLine const*, TCharStream const*, void const* (*)(__CTRun const*, __CFString const*, void*), void*, std::__1::shared_ptr<TBidiLevelsProvider>*, unsigned int, unsigned char> const&, long, double, double, std::__1::function<unsigned char (long)>) + 112
6   com.apple.CoreText              0x00007fff8e74f75a TTypesetter::SuggestClusterBreak(long, double, double, std::__1::function<unsigned char (long)>) const + 176
7   com.apple.CoreText              0x00007fff8e74f66d CTTypesetterSuggestClusterBreak + 71
8   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8d4afcaa -[NSATSLineFragment layoutForStartingGlyphAtIndex:characterIndex:minPosition:maxPosition:lineFragmentRect:] + 518
9   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8d4ae64e -[NSATSTypesetter _layoutLineFragmentStartingWithGlyphAtIndex:characterIndex:atPoint:renderingContext:] + 2777
10  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8d4e1c79 -[NSATSTypesetter layoutParagraphAtPoint:] + 149
11  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8db59b45 -[NSTypesetter _layoutGlyphsInLayoutManager:startingAtGlyphIndex:maxNumberOfLineFragments:maxCharacterIndex:nextGlyphIndex:nextCharacterIndex:] + 4043
12  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8d4e0c9d -[NSTypesetter layoutCharactersInRange:forLayoutManager:maximumNumberOfLineFragments:] + 202
13  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8d4e0b81 -[NSATSTypesetter layoutCharactersInRange:forLayoutManager:maximumNumberOfLineFragments:] + 1107
14  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8d4df219 -[NSLayoutManager(NSPrivate) _fillLayoutHoleForCharacterRange:desiredNumberOfLines:isSoft:] + 1306
15  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8d588ad9 _NSFastFillAllLayoutHolesForGlyphRange + 1435
16  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8db17199 -[NSTextView(NSPrivate) _ensureLayoutCompleteForRect:withExtensionFactor:minimumExtensionDistance:repetitions:] + 568
17  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8db1722c -[NSTextView(NSPrivate) _ensureLayoutCompleteForRect:withExtension:] + 84
18  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8dae83ed -[NSTextView prepareContentInRect:] + 203
19  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8d5f0758 __48-[NSView _pullInTilesByDrawingAndAddingSubviews]_block_invoke + 599
20  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8d5efe90 -[NSView _performWorkOnTilesFromRect:renderedContentRect:maximumRect:scrollVelocity:handler:] + 2411
21  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8d5ef41a -[NSView _pullInTilesByDrawingAndAddingSubviews] + 1007
22  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8d5ef012 -[NSView _pullInExtraTilesForOverdraw] + 87
23  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8d5eef7e -[NSView _doIdlePrefetch] + 59
24  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8d5eca8a __CreateIdleRunLoopObserverWithHandler_block_invoke + 237
25  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff85ba10a7 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
26  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff85ba1017 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391
27  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff85b92893 __CFRunLoopRun + 995
28  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff85b92275 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309
29  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff80c74f0d RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 226
30  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff80c74cb7 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 479
31  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff80c74abc _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 65
32  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8d40928e _DPSNextEvent + 1434
33  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8d4088db -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 122
34  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8d3fc9cc -[NSApplication run] + 553
35  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8d3e7803 NSApplicationMain + 940
36  com.apple.dt.Xcode              0x00000001060eeb6f 0x1060ed000 + 7023
37  com.apple.dt.Xcode              0x00000001060eeb00 0x1060ed000 + 6912
```

[image]

Comment: I think a project that reopens when you start Xcode 4.6.3 will crash the system. Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920158/how-to-turn-off-reopen-projects-on-xcode-launch-in-xcode-4-1-later. Otherwise make a new project in Xcode 5.0.2 an try to open the project in Xcode 4.6.3

Comment: Thanks! I have done as that post mentioned, only crash once now. And I have to mention that I have some versions of the one project, they always crash before but now only one version crash. I also found it maybe cause by some non-normal code. I opened the file I last edited and commented some unfinished code, then I can open the project normally and not crash. This situation let me remenber

Comment: I ever edited a class file, written some code but not finished, open another file. And then reopen previous class file, it only show me one screen content but this file have more content than one screen could show. It could not be scrolled! Before the Xcode crash now, it become not scrolled first!

Comment: crash again and I found that when I reopen and stay at the class file which has code that ever cause crash when running, it will crash again. If I browse another file, it will not crash. Strange thing, can't understand.

Comment: I think the class is corrupted and you have to write it again. Xcode sometimes crashes when there is some corrupted code and when you want to reopen the project it will start at the corrupted file and starts crashing again. I know this issue. Xcode is sometimes a buggy program. There is nothing that we can do about it!