# How to load ~/.bash_profile when entering bash from within zsh?

Tags: bash, macos, shell, zsh, zshrc

I've used bash for two years, and just tried to switch to zsh shell on my OS X via homebrew. And I set my default (login) shell to zsh, and I confirmed it's set properly by seeing that when I launch my Terminal, it's zsh shell that is used in default.

However, when I try to enter bash shell from within zsh, it looks like not loading `~/.bash_profile`, since I cannot run my command using aliases, which is defined in my `~/.bash_profile` like `alias julia="~/juila/julia"`, etc.. Also, the prompt is not what I set in the file and instead return `bash-3.2$`.

For some reasons, when I set my login shell to bash, and enter zsh from within bash, then `~/.zshrc` is loaded properly.

So why is it not loaded whenever I run `bash` from within zsh? My `~/.bash_profile` is symbolic linked to `~/Dropbox/.bash_profile` in order to sync it with my other computers. Maybe does it cause the issue?

Comment: are your aliases available after your run `source ~/.bash_profile`?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

An interactive `bash` reads your `~/.bash_profile` if it's a login shell, or your `~/.bashrc` if it's not a login shell.

A typical `.bash_profile` will contain something like:

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then . ~/.bashrc; fi
```

so `.bashrc` can contain commands to be executed by either login or non-login shells.

If you run `bash -l` rather than just `bash`, it should read your `.bash_profile`.

Reference: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html

Comment: Thanks. I defined the `~/.bashrc` loading on the top of my `~/.bash_profile`, but defined almost all settings, including aliases and environmental variables in my `~/.bash_profile`, not `~/.bashrc`. And I confirm that `bash -l` loads it successfully from within zsh.

Comment: I don't know why oh-my-zsh updates, it removes every change to .zshrc.

Answer (score 174):

Open `~/.zshrc`, and at the very bottom of the file, add the following:

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_profile ]; then 
    . ~/.bash_profile;
fi
```

Every time you open the terminal, it will load whatever is defined in `~/.bash_profile` (if the file exist). With that, you can keep your custom settings for **zsh** (colors, and etc). And you get to keep your custom shell settings in `.bash_profile` file.

This is much cleaner than using `bash -l` IMO.

If you prefer putting your settings in `.bashrc`, or `.bash_login`, or `.profile` , you can do the same for them.

---

Similarly, you could also move the common profile settings to separate file, i.e. `.my_common_profile`, and add the following to both `.bash_profile` and `.zshrc`:

```
if [ -f ~/.my_common_profile ]; then 
    . ~/.my_common_profile;
fi
```

Comment: what does '-f ~/.bash_profile' and  '. ~/.bash_profile'  mean?    A shell command??

Comment: The 1st one means "does this file exist?". The 2nd one means "load this file please".

Comment: @sodino this might help https://stackoverflow.com/q/638975/1035008

Comment: Thanks!!! I take this very comprehensive documentation after you.       https://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/index.html

Answer (score 37):

For those who have just installed zsh and want their alias from bash to work on zsh do the following

1. Open .zshrc file in vim like so

   ```
    vi ~/.zshrc
   ```
2. Scroll to the bottom
3. click "i" to enable write mode
4. Tell zsh to load items from bash_profile when needed like so

   ```
   source ~/.bash_profile
   ```
5. Write and quit like so

   ```
   :wq
   ```
6. Refresh your zsh like so

   ```
   source ~/.zshrc
   ```

   That's it. Now all your saved alias in .bash_profile will be ready to use in zsh.

Answer (score 28):

To complement @Keith Thompson's excellent answer:

**macOS**:

As [@chepner puts it succinctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22502759/mac-os-x-10-9-setting-permanent-environment-variables/22502848#comment34240983_22502848) (emphasis mine):

> In OS X, bash is not used as part of the initial [at boot time] login process, and the Terminal.app (or other terminal emulators) process exists outside any pre-existing bash sessions, so **each new window [or tab - read: interactive bash shell] (by default) treats itself as a new login session**.

As a result, **some OSX users only ever create `~/.bash_profile`**, and never bother with `~/.bashrc`, because ALL interactive bash shells are *login* shells.

**Linux**:

On Linux, the situation is typically *reversed*: 
`bash` shells created interactively are [interactive] *NON-login* shells, so it is `~/.bashrc` that matters.

As a result, **many Linux users only ever deal with `~/.bashrc`**.

---

To maintain **bash profiles that work on BOTH platforms**, use the technique @Keith Thompson mentions:

- Put your definitions (aliases, functions, ...) in `~/.bashrc`
- Add the following line to `~/.bash_profile`

```sh
[[ -f ~/.bashrc ]] && . ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: Thanks for the excellent follow-up! How do you think about the idea that I only leave `if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then . ~/.bashrc; fi` in my `~/.bash_profile`, and move everything others to `~/.bashrc`?

Comment: @Gardecolo: I think that's a good idea (there's a largely hypothetical caveat: on platforms where a `bash` login session is created during boot - as stated, OSX is NOT one of them - you could argue that all `export` statements should go into `~/.bash_profile`, because they only need to be executed _once_, and repeating them for every new bash shell is unnecessary - in practice, though, I doubt that it matters).

Answer (score 20):

Copy the contents from ~/.bash_profile and paste them at the bottom of ~/.zshrc file.

Answer (score 8):

For ZSH users on MacOs, I ended up with a one liner.

At the very bottom of the ***~/.zshrc*** I added the following line :

```
bash -l
```

What it does is simply load the ***.bash_profile*** settings(aliases, function, export $PATH, ...)

If you decide to get rid of ZSH and go back to plain BASH, you'll be back to normal with no hassle at all.

Comment: This works but it creates another bash shell inside zsh and you lose zsh functionality and colors.

Comment: Instead of this, at the very bottom of `~/.zshrc` file, add `source ~/.bash_profile` .

Answer (score 4):

If this is something that you do infrequently, or it just isn't appropriate to make changes, you can also 'source' the *.bash_profile* after launching the child bash shell.

```
. ~/.bash_profile
```

This will pull in the settings you make in the *.bash_profile* script for the life of that shell session. In most cases, you should be able to repeat that command, so it's also an easy way to test any changes that you make without needing to do a full login, as well as bring all of your existing shell sessions up-to-date if you make upgrades to the *.bash_profile* &/or *.bashrc* files.

Answer (score 4):

For macOS Big Sur (Version 11.5.2)

- Open `.zshrc`

  - For example: `sudo nano ~/.zshrc`
- At the end of the file add `source ~/.bash_profile`

Every time you open the terminal the contents inside the bash profile will be loaded.

Answer (score 2):

Recently I installed [oh-my-zsh](https://ohmyz.sh/) on OS X and set `zsh` as default shell and faced the same problem.
I [solved](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues/3807#issuecomment-187930190) this problem by adding `source ~/.bash_profile` at the end of `.zshrc` file.

Answer (score 1):

I am using a zsh framework called [oh my zsh](https://ohmyz.sh/) and I have tried most of the solutions listed here and it broke the format for my custom theme. However, these steps worked for me.

1. Add new alias(es) at the bottom of my ***.bash_profile***

   `vi ~/.bash_profile`
2. Make **zsh** to load items from ***.bash_profile***

   `source ~/.bash_profile`
3. Refresh **zsh**

   `source ~/.zshrc`
4. Restart OSX Terminal app
5. Try your new alias!

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to be "profile-centric", you can create `.profile` as a single source of truth, then load it from both `.bash_profile` and `.zprofile`.

*.profile*

```sh
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin:$PATH"
# etc., etc.
```

*.bash_profile* and *.zprofile*

```
if [ -f ~/.profile ]; then 
    . ~/.profile;
fi
```

I found this helped bash scripts find the right `PATH`, etc., and helped me keep configuration in one place.