# Is there a way to not expose credentials in the code?

Tags: python, environment-variables

I've been using ipython notebook and there are 2 information (`SNOW_USER` and `PASSWORD`) that I need to pass so I can connect to the database. I don't want to expose it for security reasons.

I tried to set as `ENV VAR` (environmental variables) saving it on my `.bash_profile` and also on `.profile` using `export SNOW_USER='abc'` but it doesn't seem ipython can find it.

```
import os
print os.environ['SNOW_USER']
```

I also tried:

```
%env
```

But the variables are not showing there either.

Any thoughts on how to do it?

Comment: Did you logout and in after? Or  `source ~/.bash_profile`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yes. I shutdown the notebook and open it afterwards.

Comment: Hmm, that should work.

Comment: Try logout. If you open the notebook from your window manager but it hasn't been restarted, you are still using the old environment.

Comment: @tdelaney, they have logged out and back in so that should not be the issue no?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I think OP meant that s/he shut down the IPython Notebook and restarted it, not the notebook computer...

Comment: @MattDMo, ah ok, I asked if they had logged out, when I saw yes I presumed they had :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to create a file `.env` somewhere with in it :

```
export SNOW_USER="snow_user"
export PASSWORD="password"
```

and then source it :

```
source .env
```

Or just source you `bash_profile` file :

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I haven't tried creating `.env`.  It worked out. I'm not sure why the `bash_profile` didn't work.

Comment: @lizzie, I thought  you added to `~/.bash_profille`  as per your question and comment?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I did add to my bash_profile. What I didn't have was the `.env` file.

Comment: @lizzie the `.env` or the `bash_profile` work the same. You just have to source it somehow. But usually it is good to have a `.env` at the root of your project.

Comment: @Till Great to know!

Comment: @lizzie, you must not have  actually logged out, whatever is in `.profile` would have been executed on login and when you restarted a shell your .bash_profile would have run so there is no reason I know of that .env would work when the others didn't unless of course you did not do what I asked in my original comment

Comment: @lizzie ... are you really using `bash`? My linux mint uses `dash` and `dash` uses .profile not .bash_profile. `ls -l /bin/sh` should tell you.

Comment: @tdelaney the output from `ls -l /bin/sh` says wheel. I'm using zshell AFAIK.

Comment: There is a link about loading `.bash_profile` with `zsh` : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23233603/how-to-load-bash-profile-when-entering-bash-from-within-zsh