# how to write a function in bash_profile

Tags: linux, bash, function, shell, alias

how can we write a simple regular function which i can put in my bashprofile
which can be used to secure console to any host i want.

but my secure console has to go through a jump host. that is the issue.

```
function func_name () {
 ssh jumphostname; 
 sc $hostname # from jump host secure console to another host given as input from terminal
}
```

this function only making to login in to jump host but not to secureconsole in to another host from there.

-bash-4.1$func_name host.me.com
should give me console to host.me.com via jumphost

is function for this not possible?
do i have to write a script?

Comment: No you need to be much more specific, and I suggest you re-word your question to be more appropriate, as this isn't so much about how to write a bash function, but more about ssh remote control from a local station.

Comment: When I try to put together what you're trying to do, I end up with wondering why you can't just `ssh user@host` and work from there ?  Like I said, if you are more specific, and perhaps give a usage case scenario, then people might be able to help.  For versatile remote control and exception handling, I often use `expect` wrappers

Comment: yes. i made the question more specific.

Comment: There is an easy to follow process I explained on my other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64092588/7551807)

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I do it.

1. Create a functions folder at home
2. Write my function as a shell script
3. Reference the file as an alias in my bash_profile
4. Reset the source

Example

```
mkdir ~/.functions
echo '#!/bin/bash
      echo $1' > ~/.functions/ekho
echo 'alias ekho="sh ~/.functions/ekho"' >> ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Now you can call your method from any location for ever ever.

```
ekho "Wow"
```

Comment: I was looking for something like this and it helped me creating an alias that also takes parameters. The only difference is I added the alias to ~/.bashrc instead of ~/.bash_profile, which is what I needed.

Comment: This is the "right" way to do it, but if the person asking the question is merely trying to make a function (or anything at all) work from .bash_profile, then is it really helpful to add complexity by introducing a file that must be read for the function?

Answer (score 0):

You should not use commands in a test `[ ]` unless you simulate a variable with `$( )` arround the commands. Still not sure `SSH` will return something to the test. `SSH` needs the `TTY` you like connect to, and not the `TTY` you in at. This will causes problems!

An example without SSH ...

```
suleiman@antec:~$ if [ "$(cat ~/test.txt)" ]; then echo "Hello World"; else echo "failed"; fi
Hello World
suleiman@antec:~$ if [ "$(cat /this/file/dont/exsist 2>/dev/null)" ]; then echo "Hello World"; else echo "failed"; fi
failed
```

---

**Addition:**

> -bash: sc: command not found

This means you have NOT installed the `spreadsheet` on the host.

> This function only making to login in to jump host but not to
>   secureconsole in to another host from there.

What you trying to do ?

Do you know what `SSH` does ?
It opens remote `TTYs`, or with other words: it **opens** a remote **secure console**.

You cant run a script and put somewhere a ssh login in it, and then think all code after that will be in the new console, neither will that happen.

You can run `ssh` on a console, so you get your own TTY and put some commands in it. Or you use `ssh` in combination with some commands in a script, like

```
ssh user@host echo "Hello World!"
```

You can also pass some variables or text though `ssh` via

```
echo "Hello World!" | ssh user@host cat
```

There isnt much more you can do with it and you shouldn't!

Comment: we create alias in bash_profile. it goes through. But after logging in i want to run sc command on that host from that jump host.

Comment: `ssh user@host sc` is what you looking for ?.. I updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

Below link would help you to go ahead

```
ssh username@host_address "command to execute"
```

For example output:

```
arul@OA2:~/work/images$ ssh arul@localhost echo "hai"
arul@localhost's password: 
hai
arul@OA2:~/work/images$
```

ssh arul@localhost command will login and "echo hai" command printed in currently logged in prompt"

Citation: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-execute-command-using-ssh/

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note that link-only answers can usually be improved by actually explaining your intended answer yourself, including anything directly relevant from the link, and linking only for further information. See e.g. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Comment: Thanks for your valuable inputs @kojiro

Answer (score 0):

I would write this

```
con.sole() {
    if ! ssh -T jumphostname true; then
        printf 'Jump host "%s" not available.\n' jumphostname >&2
        return 1
    fi
    sc "$@"
}
```

[The square brace isn't part of the `if` statement syntax.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#if_.5Bgrep_foo_myfile.5D) It is a separate command, the same as `test`.

Comment: above script gets me till jumphost. it cant sc after that                             con.sole hostname.com
Warning: Permanently added 'jumphost.com (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
-bash: sc: command not found

Answer (score -2):

Its because you dont leave a whitespace between the if and the [...
The the correct sintax you want is...

```
function con.sole
{
    if [ ssh jumphostname ]; then
        sc $1;
    else 
        echo "host not available"
    fi 
}
```

Greetings from Mexico!

Comment: after leaving space also it had -bash: [: ssh: unary operator expected         so i added single quotes. it works now but real problem still exists.

Comment: What are trying to do? Do you want to connect a server and then connect to another?... local->server1->server2?

Comment: I think you need to learn what `[` means in shell; it's not a grouping operator.